# How to install Vaadin CDI with Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, vaadin, cdi, tomcat8, vaadin8

I have read a lot of threads about cdi and tomcat. Finally, most of the users decided to launch vaadin with TomEE instead of TomCat.
I don't need all TomEE features, and my project leader want me to use Tomcat 8, that's why I have to find a way to deploy it with tomcat.

I also tried to import cdi into my Tomcat project with the following configuration, but I still have errors. Hope someone could help me. Thanks

**WEB-INF/beans.xml** is empty
**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <!-- Enable Weld CDI, also needs META-INF/context.xml entry -->
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

**META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
              factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

**Dependencies for CDI**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Errors**

> **[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]** org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
>   at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startExtensions(WeldStartup.java:579)
>
> **[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]** org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception
>   invoking method manageApp  java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext]
>
> **[RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1]** org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception
>   invoking method createStandardContext 
>   javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method
>   manageApp

Comment: Did you try upgrading to Weld 2.4.4.Final ?  2.2 would have a guava dependency which is likely conflicting with Vaadin or something else in your pom.

Comment: I tried to remove Weld and I got only one error, java.lang.NullPointerException at com.vaadin.cdi.internal.AnnotationUtil.getUiBeans(AnnotationUtil.java:80) but Im gonna try with 2.4.4 weld

Comment: It seems working with 2.4.4!